# azure mobile app cordova ripple facebook authentication issue

Tags: visual-studio-cordova, azure-mobile-services

I'm using VS2015 with Update 2, and azure-mobile-app cordova plugin is ver. 2.0.0-beta4

I follow the quick start of azure mobile app and use cordova with facebook authentication.
When I run the app through VS2015 in ripple, the authentication popped up. But after entering id/pwd, the pop up window didn't close and the authentication didn't complete.

The issue won't show in device or emulator.

I saw [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client/issues/81) that ms guy said this bug is fixed in google authentication, but how about facebook auth in azure mobile app cordova ripple?

My customers mentioned that same issue as well.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: do you see any errors in console?

Comment: Thank you Alex for your prompt reply.
I found there's solution for this in azure mobile official site. thanks a lot.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-cordova-how-to-use-client-library/#auth

How to: Configure your Mobile App Service for External Redirect URLs.